# sqlalchemy different value from `len(query.all())` and `query.count()`

Tags: python, count, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

This is an example code.

A Document has many Comment(s)

PostComment extends Comment (with sqlalchemy polymorphic feature)

Some query returns different result between `len(query.all())` and `query.count()`

- sqlalchemy version : 1.0.8
- mysql version : 5.6.25

See main function below.

What happened?

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, Float, Boolean, ForeignKey, String, Unicode, DateTime, Date, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:root@192.168.59.103:3306/document')

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine

class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'document'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'comment'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(50))
    document_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('document.id'), primary_key=True)
    document = relationship('Document', backref=backref('comments', lazy='dynamic'))

    __mapper_args__= {
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'comment',
        'polymorphic_on' : type,
    }


class PostComment(Comment):
    __tablename__ = 'post_comment'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('comment.id'), primary_key=True)
    ready = Column(Boolean)

    __mapper_args__= {
        'polymorphic_identity' : 'post_comment',
    }



def main():
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    d1 = Document()
    DBSession.add(d1)

    d2 = Document()
    DBSession.add(d2)

    c1 = PostComment(document=d1, ready=True)
    DBSession.add(c1)

    c2 = PostComment(document=d1, ready=True)
    DBSession.add(c2)

    c3 = PostComment(document=d2, ready=True)
    DBSession.add(c3)

    c4 = PostComment(document=d2, ready=True)
    DBSession.add(c4)

    DBSession.commit()

    query = d1.comments.filter(PostComment.ready==True)

    print len(query.all())      # returns 2
    print query.count()         # returns 8


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Updates

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count

It says "Return a count of rows this Query would return.".

Comment: I'm using by pass query. `query = d1.comments.filter(PostComment.ready==True, PostComment.id==Comment.id)` But this is not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you get 8 as result instead of 2? Because you get a query which is a *cartesian product* (8 = 2 * 2 * 2).
In turn, this happens because you have `dynamic` relationship *with* `inheritance`, which creates `select` from both tables (`comment` and `post_comment`) without any predicate between them.

Why the first query returns just `2`? Well, because you are asking for actual mapped instances, `sqlalchemy` is smart enough to filter out the duplicates, although the underlying `SQL` statement does return 8 rows as well.

Add a `join` to your query to fix this:

```
query = d1.comments.join(PostComment).filter(PostComment.ready == True)
```

Comment: [sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count) it says "Return a count of rows this Query would return.". Isn't it wrong semantically?

Comment: It is not. The query actually returns 8 rows. *But* only when results of the query is converted to a list of mapped objects, this is reduced to just 2.

Comment: The real problem is that you by navigating a `Document.comments` you technically get a query for `Comment` table. When you then add filter with `PostComment` table, it is not clear in the context that you would like to assume there should be a `join` between `Comment` and `PostComment`. If you change you query to that below (will also edit the answer), it should do what you really want:     `query = d1.comments.join(PostComment).filter(PostComment.ready == True)`

Comment: It's just what I want. Thank you @van .

Comment: I am unsure if this auto-deduplication hidden magic is appreciated. 

This can create all sorts of bugs on paginated queries in which `.all()` *with page offsets* trigger the auto-deduplication behavior, but a `.count()` for the total records could trigger something that _does not_ corresponds if each page was aggregated and then counted.

I would rather see the duplicated values, as it literally corresponds to what I have written as a query –– Then the problem is in my face and it's up to me to figure out why my query is bad (on missing a join, as you very well explained)